# GitHub Pages mangling syntax highlighting after upgrade to Jekyll 3

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, rouge

I use Github Pages for my personal website. They're upgrading from Jekyll 2 to Jekyll 3 and sending deprecation warnings. I complied with their warnings and switched from redcarpet to kramdown and from pygments to rouge. When I build locally (with `bundle exec jekyll serve`) everything works. But when I push the changes the syntax highlighting gets mangled wherever I have `linenos` in my code blocks.

This is the code block:

```
{% highlight python linenos %}
'''
scrape lyrics from vagalume.com.br
(author: thiagomarzagao.com)
'''

import json
import time
import pickle
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get each genre's URL
basepath = 'http://www.vagalume.com.br'
r = requests.get(basepath + '/browse/style/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
genres = [u'Rock']
          u'Ax\u00E9',
          u'Forr\u00F3',
          u'Pagode',
          u'Samba',
          u'Sertanejo',
          u'MPB',
          u'Rap']
genre_urls = {}
for genre in genres:
    genre_urls[genre] = soup.find('a', class_ = 'eA', text = genre).get('href')

# get each artist's URL, per genre
artist_urls = {e: [] for e in genres}
for genre in genres:
    r = requests.get(basepath + genre_urls[genre])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    counter = 0
    for artist in soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'top'):
        counter += 1
        print 'artist {} \r'.format(counter)
        artist_urls[genre].append(basepath + artist.get('href'))
    time.sleep(2) # don't reduce the 2-second wait (here or below) or you get errors

# get each lyrics, per genre
api = 'http://api.vagalume.com.br/search.php?musid='
genre_lyrics = {e: {} for e in genres}
for genre in artist_urls:
    print len(artist_urls[genre])
    counter = 0
    artist1 = None
    for url in artist_urls[genre]:
        success = False
        while not success: # foor loop in case your connection flickers
            try:
                r = requests.get(url)
                success = True
            except:
                time.sleep(2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
        hrefs = soup.find_all('a')
        for href in hrefs:
            if href.has_attr('data-song'):
                song_id = href['data-song']
                print song_id
                time.sleep(2)
                success = False
                while not success:
                    try:
                        song_metadata = requests.get(api + song_id).json()
                        success = True
                    except:
                        time.sleep(2)
                if 'mus' in song_metadata:
                    if 'lang' in song_metadata['mus'][0]: # discard if no language info
                        language = song_metadata['mus'][0]['lang']
                        if language == 1: # discard if language != Portuguese
                            if 'text' in song_metadata['mus'][0]: # discard if no lyrics
                                artist2 = song_metadata['art']['name']
                                if artist2 != artist1:
                                    if counter > 0:
                                        print artist1.encode('utf-8') # change as needed
                                        genre_lyrics[genre][artist1] = artist_lyrics
                                    artist1 = artist2
                                    artist_lyrics = []
                                lyrics = song_metadata['mus'][0]['text']
                                artist_lyrics.append(lyrics)
                                counter += 1
                                print 'lyrics {} \r'.format(counter)

    # serialize
    with open(genre + '.json', mode = 'wb') as fbuffer:
        json.dump(genre_lyrics[genre], fbuffer)
{% endhighlight %}
```

This is what I see locally:

[image]

This is what I see on Github Pages:

[image]

(Without `linenos` the syntax highlighting works fine.)

What could be happening?

Comment: please, post your code as `text` not as `image`. There is a way to display both code blocks: with and without `linenos`, but we'll need to see your code to trying to fix it!

Comment: Sorry about that. It's posted now.

Comment: No problem! :) I'll try to reproduce your code block and get back to you with an answer, ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it!

Your code block seems to be fine. No problem there.

Make sure you have added this into your `_config.yml`:

```
highlighter: rouge
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

Probably what you're missing is `kramdown input: GFM`, isn't it?

Well, I tested locally and worked fine. When [uploaded to GitHub](http://virtuacreative.github.io/test/2016/welcome-to-jekyll1/), worked fine as well. Should work for you too.

Let me know how it goes, ok? :)

---

UPDATE!

Add this to your stylesheet and check how it goes:

`.lineno { width: 35px; }`

Looks like it's something about your CSS styles that is breaking the layout! Keep tweaking your CSS and you're gonna be fine!

Comment: This is the [path](https://github.com/VirtuaCreative/test) to my "test" repo, if you want to check the source.

Comment: Thank you so much for going through all this trouble! Indeed, I was missing `kramdown: input: GFM`. Somehow adding that didn't solve the issue though. I inspected your HTML (view-source:http://virtuacreative.github.io/test/2016/welcome-to-jekyll1/) and it's practically identical to the HTML I have, except that your code block is enclosed within a `<figure class="highlight">` tag and mine is enclosed within a `<div class="highlight">` tag instead. Other than that all the rest seems to be the same (I put my HTML in a gist: https://gist.github.com/thiagomarzagao/1fa0c6776ab207a7a086).

Comment: So, somewhere in my repo I must be doing something terribly stupid that's mangling my HTML. I guess I'll keep tweaking here and there until I find out what it is.

Comment: No trouble at all! Hmm.. interesting... perhaps it's not your html that is messed, might be your CSS styles...

Comment: Now, the most odd thing is: when the code block comes from back sticks ( ```language), the html is compiled to a `<div>` tag. When comes from `{% highlight %}`, it's compiled to a `<figure>` tag ...

Comment: I gave a look at your repo and I saw two things in your `_config.yml` that called my attention: (1) there's still no `input: GFM` there - don't forget to add it. (2): You use the plugin `jekyll-paginate`. It's not included by default into Jekyll 3.x, so you need to add it to your `Gemfile` as  `gem 'jekyll-paginate'`.

Comment: Hey, look: your local browser image shows the line numbers in one character space each! Instead of `10`, you can see it's `1` then `0`; for `11`, you see `1` then `1` again and so on. I'm quite sure that it's your CSS that is causing your issue!! Inspect element on your browser and change the width of this table column to check if that's it! For me this add some space to the line numbers' column: `.lineno { width: 35px; }`. Just test that!

Comment: Ha! That was spot on: I added `.lineno { width: 35px; }` to my syntax.css file and now the line numbers are no longer one character each, so they appear correctly. The code block is still not entirely unmangled though - the first 10 lines or so and last 10 lines or so are unnumbered and the lines that don't fit the code block horizontally are wrapped. But I guess that's a matter of keep tweaking syntax.css until I get it right. Many thanks! (Also: good eye for patterns! I had stared at those line numbers for hours and didn't realize they were 10, 11, 12, etc).

Comment: Oh, about the `kramdown: input: GFM`, I had added it but served only locally (I managed to reproduce the mangling locally by installing `rouge` and `kramdown` from `bundler`).

Comment: Awesome! I'll update the answer adding the CSS `lineno` class thing, would you mark my answer as correct? :) You know, it helps...! haha

Comment: Thanks! Happy Jekylling! :) If you need something else, here we are! ;)