# What have I missed in jekyll and github pages to make syntax highlighting work?

Tags: css, github, jekyll, syntax-highlighting, github-pages

Disclaimer: This is my first ever website project, in order to learn about html, css etc. I probably need a 'for idiots' guide'

I have a jekyll/github pages site [here](https://github.com/DaveRGP/Pokemon_FieldStudies). I have read the jekyll documentation [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#highlighting-code-snippets), which suggests all you need to do is stick the liquid tag in. Which I have, for example [here](https://github.com/DaveRGP/Pokemon_FieldStudies/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2016-05-25-your-code-evolved.md).

Further research has pointed out I need to set up my config file, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323301/github-pages-mangling-syntax-highlighting-after-upgrade-to-jekyll-3) which I have [here](https://github.com/DaveRGP/Pokemon_FieldStudies/blob/gh-pages/_config.yml). I also have a .css I copied from a site called sciviews which is [here](https://github.com/DaveRGP/Pokemon_FieldStudies/blob/gh-pages/css/syntax.css) and I've made a link into the .css to call it [here](https://github.com/DaveRGP/Pokemon_FieldStudies/blob/gh-pages/_layouts/default.html).

However, my page still [displays in black on white in code blocks](http://davergp.github.io/Pokemon_FieldStudies/blog/2016/05/25/your-code-evolved). What have I missed?

*EDIT:* I believe I've made another error, the source of my syntac .css was (i think) [here](https://github.com/DaveRGP/SciViews.github.io/blob/master/_sass/_syntax.scss). Is .scss maybe not compatible with this process as I've implemented it?

Comment: I created a simple guide for front-end devs who want to use Jekyll: http://jekyllcodex.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your html ( inside the head tag ), you are referencing an incorrect path to "syntax.css"

Change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/syntax.css" type="text/css">
```

To:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Pokemon_FieldStudies/css/syntax.css" type="text/css">
```

*Edit*

Following your edit, it seems the code inside syntax.css is a raw scss file. Such files need to be processed before they could be served to the client.

I suggest you read about SCSS and how to compile it ( A simple google search will yield more than enough tutorials ).

In case you're interested in a shortcut, you can use an online compiler such as http://www.sassmeister.com/ but that will require you to define a value for some of the missing variables defined in the scss file.

Comment: Potentially that has worked, do you know if I'm going to need to rebuild my posts to get it to be visible? It's still just coming up grey on black.

Comment: Yes, the fix will be reflected only when you have rebuilt your jekyll site, and re uploaded it.

Comment: by which I mean I will have to go back and recompile all the posts from .rmd to .md on the local machine and then push it though? or just make the change to the .html above and then push it up?

Comment: Recompile the rmd files to md and push.

Comment: OK,. done both those and it's not worked. I know the page has refreshed because I've broken the links to the plots (which I expected) page in question: http://davergp.github.io/Pokemon_FieldStudies/blog/2016/05/25/your-code-evolved

Comment: Your http://davergp.github.io/Pokemon_FieldStudies/css/syntax.css is still in its scss format.